# React auto reload with vagrant

Tags: reactjs, vagrant

I have one issue with react auto reload browser/server.
If I run react on my local env. Everything is okay. Browser reloads.
But if I run react inside vagrant, browser reloads only when I edit react files via terminal > vagrant , but not in my text editor.
Maybe so thoughts? Maybe there are some vagrant conf that I need to know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuring Webpack to `webpack-dev-server --watch-poll` should resolve your problem.

By default Webpack is subsribed to files changes via [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), but:

> Notification via inotify requires the kernel to be aware of all relevant filesystem events, which is not always possible for networked filesystems such as NFS.

So enabling **poll** will force Webpack to:

> Check every few hundred milliseconds to see if your files have been updated.

**Credits**:

- [Webpack watch in Vagrant / Docker](http://andrewhfarmer.com/webpack-watch-in-vagrant-docker/).
- [Running
  the server does not compile files or reload page in windows.](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/155#issuecomment-159140735).

Answer (score 15):

There is a simpler method than the one posted above, at least assuming you used the recommended `create-react-app` to create your app.

Add this line: `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to a file called `.env` that should exist or be created in the root folder of your project.

[This link](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) tells you more about environment variables & also contains info on the polling setting above. Be sure to read it so you know about the different `.env` file types and decide whether or not you want to use polling in all cases.

Comment: Pretty cool that this worked. Thanks for the link to the documentation. Helped me greatly.

Comment: instantly helpful for plain ubuntu box with nodejs install not using webpack. thank you!